# WPF Custom multiple NumericUpDown always firing one event

Tags: c#, wpf, numericupdown

I'm using a custom [NumericUpDown](https://wpfnumericupdown.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NumericUpDown/NumericUpDown.xaml.cs) controls in my WPF project. Each of them have their own method assigned to its ValueChanged event:

```
<eisiWare:NumericUpDown x:Name="AGradeUpDown" />
<eisiWare:NumericUpDown x:Name="BGradeUpDown" />
<eisiWare:NumericUpDown x:Name="CGradeUpDown" />
```

and code-behind:

```
public _2DEditor(string filename = null)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AGradeUpDown.ValueChanged += AGradeUpDown_ValueChanged;
    BGradeUpDown.ValueChanged += BGradeUpDown_ValueChanged;
    CGradeUpDown.ValueChanged += CGradeUpDown_ValueChanged;
}
void CGradeUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{}
BGradeUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{} 
void AGradeUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{}
```

But no matter which one of of these controls has its value changed - always triggers only CGradeUpDown_ValueChanged function, with ((eisiWare.NumericUpDown)sender).Name value showing "CGradeUpDown".

Assigning ValueChanged event like this:

```
<eisiWare:NumericUpDown x:Name="AGradeUpDown" ValueChanged="AGradeUpDown_ValueChanged" />
```

leads to firing AGradeUpDown_ValueChanged only once on loading but never on actual values changed.
What am I doing wrong or what can be the issue here? Out of ideas. =(

Comment: Yupp, that custom NumericUpDown control has a - quite stupid - bug. Check its source code - it has one **static** private field *thisReference* which it uses to raise events when the textbox value of the control changes... As you would perhaps guess already, *thisReference* is set in the NumericUpDown's constructor, thus it will always refer to the last instantiated NumericUpDown control - in your case "CGradeUpDown"... well... perhaps time for you to seek another NumericUpDown control. (Note, whenever you are out of ideas, check the source code of such 3rd-party controls ;) )

Comment: some alternatives here: https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/239450 ...https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumericUpDown ... http://markoweb2.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/wpf-numericupdown/